# TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'connect'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an existing socket.io app to update a page, someone writes a message and it appears on all the clients connected to the socket. This part works fine.

I need to read a json feed every minute and send the data in feed into same system, basically I am trying to add a secondary sender into system. (I will put 'feed reading' part into infinite loop later) Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socket = io.connect('http://host_url.com:8000');

http.get('http://json_feed_url', function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var items = JSON.parse(body)
        items.forEach(function(item, index) {
          socket.emit('update', {
                title: item.title,
                message: item.message
            });
        });
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: ", e);
});
```

When I run the script I got:

> var socket = io.connect('http://host_url.com:8000');
>                   ^
>   TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'
>       at Object. (inde
>   x.js:4:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:902:3

I derived the code from the 'message form' page and it works perfectly:

```
<script src="http://host_url.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://host_url.com:8000');

    function update_score() {
        socket.emit('update', {
            title: $("#txtTitle").val(),
            message: $("#txtMessage").val()
        });
    }
</script>
```

The message form, the host app and this feed reader are in the same folder, so it uses the same socket.io library.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after spending 2 days on it.

The host app was written 6+ months ago and I usually don't update the javascript libraries unless there is a problem/bug/new feature that I need.

So when I installed socket.io-client for this new additional module, it was a new version of the library.

The error was simply a version conflict between the client and the host. I upgraded socket.io version on the host app to latest and the code started to work.

I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use socket.io-client to simulte clients sending messages from a server.

Try:

```
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.on('event', function(data){});
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
     });
```

Comment: My thing is actually on client side, it should read the feed and send it to server. It s basically like posting system messages into a chat system.

Comment: Now i understand what you're trying to do... See https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client